# Advice on which full stack components to use for dynamic web app with backend storage

Tags: python, javascript, react, amazon, graphql

Full stack semi-noob question here: I want to build a website here in 2022 to help users with financial things like budgeting and general finance education, and I'd like to pick the right modern set of components. I want to provide:

- user authentication
- a highly dynamic website with users providing lots of data
- slick plotting controls to draw lots of graphs quickly (with interaction that responds to changes as users input data, animations, etc)
- backend storage to persist user data if they're logged in (but I'd
  like basic functionality for non-logged-in users)

I'm best in Python but I imagine JavaScript is the right language here for the frontend components. I'm thinking along these lines:

- React / Redux AWS Serverless -- I guess I can use this to run a React
  site?
- AWS Cognito for user auth
- DynamoDB and maybe GraphQL for read/write from user store (but is there something simpler? I can probably get by with a reasonably small blob of JSON per-user).

Any/all advice welcome. I've gone down the wrong path in website projects before since I'm much more a backend/machine learning person, and I know there's a lot of options I don't know about for frontend work especially.  I'd like to be able to own the code for the website but be able to easily work with graphics designers to prettify it, as well.